# Replace index value of array by filtering with array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
Arr = [1,2,3];
New = [{1:'ab'},{2:'cd'},{3:'ef'}];
```

and my out put should be

```
['ab','cd','ef'];
```

Comment: Are you able to please show what you've tried and what you're stuck on in particular with in your attempt?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+object+based+on+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const arrNew = [{ 1: "ab" }, { 2: "cd" }, { 3: "ef" }];
const result = arrNew.map((elem, i) => elem[arr[i]]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do this:

```
New.flatMap(Object.values)
```

Not sure what the first array is supposed to do. If the values are supposed to be sorted by the order of the first array, do something like this:

```
// Function that looks up the order in the Arr array
const idx = (obj) => Arr.findIndex(v => v === Number(Object.keys(obj)[0]));
const sorted = New.sort((a, b) => idx(a) - idx(b));
console.log(sorted.flatMap(Object.values));
```

Oh even faster and shorter:

```
const vals = Object.fromEntries(New.flatMap(Object.entries));
console.log(Arr.map(i => vals[i]));
```

Comment: I see you also taking care of the sorting.. For me this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const newArr = [{ 1: 'ab' }, { 2: 'cd' }, { 3: 'ef' }]

const objHash = newArr.reduce((a, c) => ((a[Object.keys(c).shift()] ??= c), a), {})

const result = arr.map((l) => objHash[l][l])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I prefer `objHash = Object.fromEntries(newArr.map(obj => [Object.keys(obj)[0], obj]))` :)

Comment: Or `Object.fromEntries(newArr.flatMap(Object.entries))`

Comment: Thank you @TrevorDixon, absolutely agree with you.. For me your answer is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the key with the `arr` index:

```js
Arr = [1,2,3];
New = [{1:'ab'},{2:'cd'},{3:'ef'}]; 
for (var idx in New){
  for (var key in New[idx]){
    Arr.forEach(r => {if (r == key) Arr[key-1] = New[idx][key]})
  }
}
console.log(Arr)
```